# Cypress in TypeScript: Mocha afterEach: Stop Runner if currentTest failed

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, cypress

Goal is if stop Cypress runner of any test failed, and these Mocha tests are written in TypeScript. The following Mocha `afterEach()` has two issues...

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />

  afterEach(() => {
    if (this.currentTest.state === 'failed' && 
      this.currentTest._currentRetry === this.currentTest._retries) {
      Cypress.runner.stop();
    }
  });
```

Here are the issues:

1. `this.currentTest.*` >>> Referring to `this` >>> `TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'`
2. `Cypress.runner.stop()` >>> `TS2339: Property 'runner' does not exist on type 'Cypress'`

How can I work this through in TypeScript and ignore it with `// @ts-ignore`?

Thank you, appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can use // @ts-ignore . Also you will need to use  regular function () {} syntax as opposed to the lambda “fat arrow” syntax () => {}

**Refer Cypress document** : https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Avoiding-the-use-of-this

> ```
> Accessing aliases as properties with this.* will not work 
> if you use arrow functions for your tests or hooks.  This is why all of our
> examples use the regular function () {} syntax as opposed to the
> lambda “fat arrow” syntax () => {}.
> ```

Code will look something like this

```
afterEach(function() {
    if (this.currentTest.state === 'failed' && 
      //@ts-ignore
      this.currentTest._currentRetry === this.currentTest._retries) {
      //@ts-ignore
      Cypress.runner.stop();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will check this out. I try not to uses `//@ts-ignore`. To me, it is like **ignoring** the issue that there **might** be a problem.

Comment: If you check the example in the cypress project 'utilities.spec.js' .  //@ts-ignore TS2351 as comment. You can include it with supporting comment and add it as part of review process . No one should use //@ts-ignore without comment and without reviewers approval.